# Finding the determinant of a Vandermonde Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need help with finding the Vandermonde determinant, I really don't understand the rules of the Vandermonde and need further explanation. This is the matrix provided:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 1/2 & 1/3
\\ 1 & 4 & 9 & 1/4 & 1/9 \\ 1 & 8 & 27 & 1/8 & 1/27
\\ 1 & 16 & 81 & 1/16 & 1/81 \end{bmatrix} $$

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $3^{rd}, 4^{th},\text{ and }\,5^{th}$ rows are the square, cube and fourth power of the $2^{nd}$ row.  So using the product formula for the expansion of a Vandermonde determinant gives

$$det = \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq 5}(a_{2,j}-a_{2,i})$$